# What does "Receiver type 'CALayer' for instance message is a forward declaration" mean here?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation, calayer, automatic-ref-counting

I'm porting a block of code from an iOS4 project to iOS5 and I'm having some troubles with ARC.  The code generates a PDF from a screen capture.

PDF Generation Code

```
UIView *captureView;
...
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, captureView.bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[captureView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

The renderInContext line

```
[captureView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
```

generates the following error.

```
Automatic Reference Counting issue
Receiver type 'CALayer' for instance message is a forward declaration
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: Just to be clear, captureView is a UIView?

Comment: Yes, probably should have added that--captureView is a UIView.

Answer (score 315, accepted):

I was able to duplicate your problem. This is what fixed it for me.

Add QuartzCore.framework to your project and this line to your .m file.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```